# easy mock's expect method gives test result passed at even false tests

Tags: java, junit, easymock

I am using easymock to test my class. After writing codes, I find out that every test succeeds even given wrong inputs. From the forums on stack overflow, I have seen that it could be avoided by using the `replay` method but it even succeeds when I use `replay` as well. I don't know what I am doing wrong? Could you please look at the code and tell me If I have to do any more things to make test fail ? I think test is not working ..

```
service = EasyMock.createMock(MyService.class);
menu = EasyMock.createMock(ISPFMenu.class);
menu.setName("name");
menu.setTitle("title");

EasyMock.expect(service.createLinesToParseEasyMock(menu)).andReturn(null);
EasyMock.replay(service);
```

Comment: So this call should return null?

Comment: My misunderstanding. Adding verify at the end is probably what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
EasyMock.verify(service);
EasyMock.verify(menu);
```

Or alternatively

```
EasyMock.verifyAll();
```

Comment: that's working !! Thank you James. Do I have to use replay before verify as well? As I read from forums, I have to use replay in order to activate the test but it seems not it is not required.

Comment: It will make no difference in the code in your question. You still want replay, for when actually test behaviour.